# Add ids of Favorite products to localstrorage (array)

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I have a Product class in React and Star icon to add the product to Favorites. I store favorite products ids in localstorage. But when I click on new product the previouos id is replaced with new product id. How can I store ids of fav products in an array?
This is my code:

```
 class Product extends React.Component {
  state = {
    favIconActive: false,
    iconColor: "black",
  };

  addToCart = () => {
    this.props.onClick();
    localStorage.setItem("Cart", this.props.card.sku);
  };

  addToFavourites = () => {
    if (this.state.favIconActive) {
      this.setState({ favIconActive: false });
      localStorage.removeItem("Favorites", this.props.card.sku);
    } else {
      this.setState({
        favIconActive: true,
      });
      localStorage.setItem("Favorites", this.props.card.sku)
    }
  };

  render() {
    const {
      card: { name, price, imgUrl, sku, color },
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <li className={styles.product}>
        <h3>{name}</h3>
        <div className={styles.imgContainer}>
          <img src={imgUrl} width="200" height="auto" alt="laptop" />
        </div>
        <span className={styles.color}>Color: {color}</span>
        <span className={styles.price}>Price: {price} $</span>
        <span className={styles.fav} onClick={this.addToFavourites}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={faStar}
            color={localStorage.getItem(JSON.parse(sku)) ? "orange" : "black"}
          />
        </span>
        <span>SKU: {sku}</span>
        <Button text="Add to cart" color={"black"} onClick={this.addToCart} />
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You favorite products ids must be stored in an array.

```
 addToFavourites = (id) => {
    if (this.state.favIconActive) {
      this.setState({ favIconActive: false });
      let favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Favorites"));
      let index = favorites.findIndex(productId => productId === id);
      favorites.splice(index, 1);
      localStorage.setItem("Favorites", JSON.stringify(favorites));
    } else {
      this.setState({
        favIconActive: true,
      });
      let favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Favorites"));
      favorites.push(id);
      localStorage.setItem("Favorites", JSON.stringify(favorites));
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing true or false for a particular state you can create a state to store index of element for which favorite icon is clicked.
Check out [this](https://medium.com/wesionary-team/creating-favorites-list-using-localstorage-in-react-part-ii-5f2766369c4f) blog for reference